# Function creating 2 identical instances of class instead of only 1

Tags: swift, xcode

I am relatively new to iOS development, any help will be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to create a new instance of a class 'Event'.

```
class Event  {

var EventName: String
var EventPhoto: UIImage?

init?(EventName: String, EventPhoto: UIImage?) {


guard !EventName.isEmpty else {
        return nil
    }


// Initial initilization of the values
self.EventName = EventName
    self.EventPhoto = EventPhoto

    // If some of the values are left blank, this will return nil to signal the problem


}
}
```

Below is the override function, which from my understanding is responsible for creating the instance:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("Cancelling Action, The Save Button Was not Pressed", log: OSLog.default,type: .debug)
    return
    }

let EventName = NewEventNameField.text ?? ""
let EventPhoto = NewEventImage.image


event = Event(EventName: EventName, EventPhoto: EventPhoto)

}
```

From my understanding, the override function should create a new instance of the class, which would then be displayed in a table view controller displaying a table of 'events'. My problem here is; when the function is called by the "create instance" button, it creates 2 identical instances with the same EventName and EventPhoto extracted from a textfield and an image in the view controller. In the tableview, there are basically 2 events that are exactly the same being displayed, which is what I am having trouble with since I don't see the code calling **init** twice anywhere, and can't figure out why the instances was created twice. After being created the 2 instances act independently and function like 2 separate instances would.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit better? I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: [Edit] Attempted to explain the problem in more detail.     Could the problem be somewhere else in the project?

Comment: can you please show the function where you call `performSegue`?

Comment: Thank You! I found the problem in my performSegue in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for the help, I found the issue in TableViewController's code file:

```
@IBAction func unwindToEventList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as?
        NewEventViewController, let event = sourceViewController.event{

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        events[selectedIndexPath.row] = event
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        }  else  {
       //Adding a new event instead of editing it.
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: events.count, section: 0)

            events.append(event)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)

        }
        //let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: events.count, section: 0)

    //events.append(event)
        //tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    }
```

Turns out that I accidentally appended the instance to the list events and inserted it into the table an extra time outside the **if** statement.